# What kind of Array is this and how do I use the data?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm using a Gravity Forms to create a form but want to do something extra with the data after submission of the form.

I'm using var_dump($_POST); to see what the resulting information that is sent is and I get this:

```
array(12) { ["input_1"]=> string(8) "John Doe" ["input_2"]=> string(11) "Some School" ["input_3"]=> string(8) "Any City" ["input_4"]=> string(7) "Alabama" ["input_5"]=> string(3) "456" ["is_submit_18"]=> string(1) "1" ["gform_submit"]=> string(2) "18" ["gform_unique_id"]=> string(0) "" ["state_18"]=> string(60) "WyJhOjA6e30iLCI5ZTU3ZGE4Mjk1MjFkYjg3MzRlNGQ5MzZjN2E5OWU1MiJd" ["gform_target_page_number_18"]=> string(1) "0" ["gform_source_page_number_18"]=> string(1) "1" ["gform_field_values"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I'm not familiar with this, yet (I learn so much from all of your help) how would I use, for example, the result from ["input_5"]?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this? `echo $_POST['input_5'];`

`$_POST` is an associate array, meaning that it is a container for multiple values (array) with named keys (associative). A numeric array doesn't have key names, and looks up values by index instead.

Associate Array - use this to store data that intuitively should be named and order does not matter

```
$myArr = [
  'Name' => 'John Doe',
  'Address' => '000 Some St.',
  'Phone' => '000-0000'
];

$myArr['Address'];
//or
$key = 'Address';
$myArr[$key]; //use a variable as a key
```

Numeric Array - use this to store the same type of data where order matters

```
$myArr = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];

$toDo = [
  'Go to the store',
  'Buy Eggs',
  'Make Breakfast',
  'Be Happy'
];

$myArr[0] //"a"

$toDo[1] //"Buy Eggs"
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that was right. Turns out I had another problem. What was confusing me was I spent some time researching this and found the var_dump($_POST); to see the output. However, I've never seen it formatted like that, so the string() was throwing me off. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @EdBooth I updated my answer with some helpful details. You might want to check it out.

Comment: As you said @m59 the confusing thing to new coders is the "sting(#)". What '["input_1"]=> string(8) "John Doe"' is saying is;

The array has a key 'input_1', and its associated value is a string of length 8 which is "John Doe".